# Oracle left outer join stops returning results when 2-table condition added

Tags: sql, oracle, join, left-join

I have an oracle sql query with a whole string of inner and left joins. However, when I add the last left join condition, it stops returning results. This may end up being a simple answer like "you can't outer join on columns from 2 tables" but I can't find any such rule for oracle, and plenty of examples showing the opposite. The sql query is:

```
  FROM a, b,
       c, d,
       e, f,
       g, h,
       (SELECT id5 FROM
        some_table WHERE
           conditions) i,
       (SELECT id7, type FROM
        some_other_table WHERE
           conditions) j
  WHERE b.time in (range) AND
        b.count <> 0 AND
        b.id1 = e.id1 AND
        e.type = g.type AND
        g.type2 = f.type2 AND
        b.id2 = a.id2(+) AND
        b.time = a.time(+) AND
        b.id3 = c.id3(+) AND
        b.time = c.time(+) AND
        c.id4 = d.id4(+) AND
        c.time = d.time(+) AND
        c.id5 = i.id5(+) AND
        c.time = h.time(+) AND
        c.id6 = h.id6(+) AND
        h.id7 = j.id7(+); --AND
        --e.type = j.type(+);
```

When I uncomment the final condition, no results are returned. Since this is supposed to be an outer join, that shouldn't happen. So, something in here must be making it not act like an outer join?

Is there a typo or error in here somewhere? Is there an oracle rule I am breaking? Anything that could be solved by switching to ANSI join format?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe there are no results that match the new query?

Comment: I'm sure there aren't. But it's an outer join. So that shouldn't affect the number of rows returned. Clarified in question.

Comment: Yeah, good point. Well, what kind of results are you getting when the line is removed? Anything that looks like it will cause a problem, specifically with rows gathered from the e or j tables?

Comment: Ansi syntax is a good thing to try. What are the results?

Comment: Another guess: you're outer joining j onto two different tables, h and e. That seems to be one thing that makes that last line so unique. See if the same thing happens if you leave the last line and take out the one above it. Otherwise, this query is way too complex for me to pick apart.

Comment: Yep, works fine with the 2nd-to-last query removed instead of the last. As of right now, guessing that the old oracle syntax doesn't allow the multiple table outer joins? I will try ANSI format.

Comment: You might want to read what the [docs have to say about outer joins](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/queries006.htm#SQLRF52334) starting with *Oracle recommends that you use the FROM clause OUTER JOIN syntax rather than the Oracle join operator. Outer join queries that use the Oracle join operator (+) are subject to the following rules and restrictions, which do not apply to the FROM clause OUTER JOIN syntax:*

Comment: @ConradFrix - The only condition that might apply is this one, which I don't actually understand: _•The (+) operator does not produce an outer join if you specify one table in the outer query and the other table in an inner query._

Comment: @user1410910 It could also be *In a query that performs outer joins of more than two pairs of tables, a single table can be the null-generated table for only one other table. For this reason, you cannot apply the (+) operator to columns of B in the join condition for A and B and the join condition for B and C.*... which is even harder to decipher.

Comment: @ConradFrix Hmm. Yah, I could see that one applying. Technically j has the (+) operator in a comparison to both h and e. And the (+) operator might not be specific enough to tell oracle what is actually being left joined to what in that case. Hadn't thought of that, since it's clear to me what I'm telling oracle to do!

Comment: I would expect the error "ORA-01417: a table may be outer joined to at most one other table" to be thrown.  Is this happening? Of course when this error is thrown, no records are returned.

Comment: @Patrick Nope, only ORA error is that this is a cursor and no records are returned. I always thought this rule applied to a situation like `a.id1 = b.id1(+) and c.id2 = b.id2(+)` without any conditions for a to c, essentially a full outer join of a and c. In my case, since I also have `a.id3 = c.id3` I thought I'd be fine.

Comment: @ConradFrix ANSI format did fix the issue. However, interesting note, there _were_ actually 3 rows in table j that matched the conditions. So, either Oracle turned the entire query into an inner join (not just the table j part) or it was doing something completely incomprehensible. In any case, not sure the rule you brought up was the issue since there was no ORA-01417, but the (+) operator clearly can't handle what I was trying to do. Thanks!

Comment: From the looks of this, is not `h.id7 = j.id7(+) AND e.type = j.type(+)` exactly `a.id1 = b.id1(+) and c.id2 = b.id2(+)`.  Perhaps your error handling (if this is a cursor in a plsql block) does not capture this.

Comment: @Patrick Also a good point. Maybe the cursor open is trapping the ORA-01417 and throwing the no rows found exception instead. I haven't added anything to tell it to do that, and it's surprising if that's native behavior for an OPEN-FOR statement, but that best explains the strange behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem (as suggested in the comments on the question) was that `h.id7 = j.id7(+) AND e.type = j.type(+)` is functionally equivalent to `a.id1 = b.id1(+) and c.id2 = b.id2(+)`. The oracle join syntax is not precise enough to see that, due to other join conditions, this is not a full outer join, so this is not allowed.

This should have caused an error, but something else in the query suppressed the error, not clear to me how that happened. In any case, switching to ANSI format allowed me to more precisely specify the join conditions, and the query worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Either you've missed something in translating your query to the simple form or I've missed something in my manipulation, but it looks like the query may not be doing what you think it should. Rewriting in standard ANSI form is more revealing:

```
FROM a
right outer join b
  on  b.id2  = a.id2
  AND b.time = a.time
right outer join c
  on  c.id3  = b.id3
  AND c.time = b.time
left outer join d
  on  d.id4  = c.id4
  AND d.time = c.time
join e
  on  e.id1 = b.id1
cross join f
join g
  on  g.type  = e.type
  AND g.type2 = f.type2
left outer join h
  on  h.time = c.time
  AND h.id6  = c.id6
left outer join(
     SELECT id5 FROM
      some_table WHERE
         conditions) i
  on  i.id5 = c.id5
left outer join(
     SELECT id7, type FROM
      some_other_table WHERE
         conditions) j
  on  j.id7 = h.id7
  and j.type = e.type   --> the criteria in question
where b.time in (range)
  AND b.count <> 0;
```

Does this look right to you? You don't mention the RIGHT OUTER joins but I'm hoping you just forgot. You do mention the INNER joins, but table f has no join criteria at all so I've used a CROSS join, hoping here also that this is your intention.

Is the join criteria for table e as it should be? According to the pattern you have set, I would expect to see "id5" here instead of "id1". Of course, you have changed all the names to submit a simplified example, so this may be meaningless. So the first thing I would suggest is that you rewrite your original code to the ANSI form like I did, using the real table and column names. You may see something.

You are correct in that adding the marked criteria should have no effect on the number of rows in the result set. That being the case, there is something else going on.

To find out what, comment out the entire last join. If you see something screwy, keep commenting out tables to get to where the problem occurs. If everything looks good, execute just the nested query that forms "table" j. I can't think of anything it might contain that could cause the situation as you explain it, but examine it anyway.

Finally, if all else fails, form queries with just tables e and j and then with just tables h and j (with their corresponding join criteria). See what happens.

Then get back here and explain to us how the problem was somewhere else the whole time. :)

Comment: I know this is an old question reading through left me wondering why I didn't comment on your answer, so you could edit it and I could select it as correct... All the criteria I listed were correct, but I removed any that weren't involved in joins. My final query basically looked like yours except I joined g before f, avoiding the cross join (no recollection why I didn't name the tables in alphabetical order there). Anyway, the original query included enough conditions to avoid a full outer join, but Oracle's syntax rules don't take that into account; ANSI format made it explicit, and worked.

Comment: Oh, and also I changed the order so that all the outer joins were left outer joins (by starting with b) and f does have join criteria with g (which you included but maybe missed due to f being alphabetically before g). There was a good reason to start with b, but no good reason to not name the tables in this question in a different order so that my simplified example started with a :p